# How can I reboot in recovery mode in a remote machine?

Tags: reboot, cloud

I got stuck in the [cannot create temp file for here-document: Read-only file system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211696/read-only-file-system/262997) problem.

I don't know how to fix up this problem (the accepted answer there is "purchase a new hard drive"). But at least I shall reboot it under recovery mode.

However, my machine is Google Compute Engine (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) and I could not go into recovery mode with the "pushing keys" method. I connect it via SSH.

In this case, how can I make it into recovery mode?

Comment: You need root access, so, assuming you have sudo access, run the command as root `sudo mount -o remount,rw /` . It is not clear why your file system is ro , that generally indicates errors. If you boot to recovery mode I am not sure it will help if you do not have someone in front of the console.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud providers generally do give this kind of access.  Instead, the recovery procedure is to use another instance.

1. Shutdown broken instance but do not terminate or delete it.
2. Boot a second instance and attach the volume from the first broken instance to the new one.
3. Perform maintenance on the newly attached disk (`fsck`, etc)

You can find more details [in this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749560/gce-is-there-access-to-the-maintenance-shell).