# run file-system checks on ubuntu server using live media

Tags: server, filesystem, boot-repair, recovery-mode

I'm getting a readonly file system error with my ubuntu server after a power outage.  I have the thumb drive I installed the server from.  It's been suggested I boot from the thumb drive and run file-system checks that detect and fix any issues, but to not run fsck.  Can someone please describe the process and commands I should run to perform the file-system checks using my live media?

here's the error I'm getting:

```
Unable to setup logging. [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/log/landscape/sysinfo.log'
run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/50-landscape-sysinfo exited with return code 1 
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd: 31: /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd: cannot create /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available: Read-only file system mktemp: failed to create file via template '/var/lib/update-notifeir/tmp.xxxxxxxxxx': Read-only file system run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/95-hwe-eol exited with return code 1 /user/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: 33: /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: cannot create /var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot: Read-only file system
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you were told not to run fsck and I'm reasonably sure this is a duplicate (though I didn't find anything exactly the same in a brief search), but there are several ways to [check for disk errors](https://linux-tips.us/how-to-check-a-disk-for-errors/). There are many tutorials online about booting to live media and how to find your drive's designation. This is possibly a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/211696/read-only-file-system (and others) so I'll leave this as a comment.